# Expanding text within expanding text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text-editor

I have found several codes providing brilliant options to have a text expand upon clicking another one. Expand/collapse functions, I believe we are all somewhat familiar with them.

What I am mainly interested in though, is how could I have expanding text show from a block of text that I already had expanded from another line?
I mean that I'd click a line and it shows another line which I can click again and shows a third one that was not visible before at all.

Is that possible in any way? Thank you very much for any feedback for which you take your time to provide in advance!

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: do you mean this? http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display_js

Comment: Sort of similar, but really not quite. As I said, what I'm looking for, is a way to have text expand from expanded text. So to put it as simply as I can: I have text a, I click text a and text b shows, then I click text b and text c shows, which didn't show before. So I'm talking 2 steps. One is revealing text b within text a, then revealing text c within text b that wasn't visible before at all.

Comment: Notepad++ http://superuser.com/a/1001818/340964

Comment: nicolallias this explains program-specific hotkey combinations. What I am interested in, is specifically what I've written above. Achieving unfolding navigation entries for my website through clicking text and not hotkeys in a program. Once more, the structure would look like this: clicking 'Categories' would make 'Category A' show up and THEN clicking 'Category A' would make 'Subcategory a' show up. So it's basically expanding text within expanding text, as the title says. I really can't be any more clear than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/julienetienne/41g9f1pt/1/

The key is to get the index, I prefer to put node-list into arrays, that way you can use first class functions.
This rough demo I made will need  a polyfill or two for IE8 support:

```js
var section = document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0];
var sectionArray = [].slice.call(section.children);
var lastElement;

section.addEventListener('click', showHide, true);

function showHide(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  var indexOfSection = sectionArray.indexOf(target);
  var elementToToggleHeight;
  // If element is a paragraph
  if (target.tagName === 'P') {
    var elementToToggle = section.children[indexOfSection + 1];

    if(indexOfSection + 1 < sectionArray.length){
      elementToToggleHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elementToToggle, null).getPropertyValue("height"),10);
      }

    if (elementToToggleHeight) {
      // Function to close all except current and first
      sectionArray.forEach(function(paragraph){
        if(paragraph !== target && paragraph !== sectionArray[0]){
        paragraph.style.height = 0;
        }
      });

    } else {
      if(elementToToggle)
      elementToToggle.style.height = '1em';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellowgreen;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p:first-child {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>The path of the righteous man is beset on all sides</p>
  <p>by the inequities of the selfish and the tyranny of evil men</p>
  <p>And I will strike down upon thee with great </p>
  <p>vengeance and furious anger those who would attempt</p>
  <p>to poison and destroy my brothers</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Wow, this is super neat!! Thank you very much for your help, I don't know if you had this around or created it just now, if the latter's the case then damn, compared to me you're VERY skilled. I love how you added the function to collapse paragraphs except for the first and the current one! You have helped me tremendously, I wonder why wasn't such an awesome code available before in my searching attempts... trust me, I did try to find an answer for a loooong time to this problem. Anyway, thanks a bunch once more and have a nice day! :)

Comment: No probs. I just created it now but I have to say It could be worth playing around with it, maybe by using display: none / block rather than height. Or even opacity.

If not it may be worth wrapping each tag so you can use better padding. If you get any problems let me know and I'll cook something up. You too Richard ;)

Comment: I found a small bug. Steps to reproduce: open all 5 lines of text. Click on 3rd. All lines will collapse but 1st and 3rd.

Comment: @Alex Pavlov That's not exactly a bug, if you take a look at the code, it specifies that when you click an expanded line then all but that and the first one should collapse. If you try to click the fourth or the fifth line, the same will happen, except that it won't be the third one to stay visible but the line that you clicked. So it's intended to behave that way.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you tagged jQuery, so I write small really simple example https://jsfiddle.net/alienpavlov/khk40ygm/2/ using it:

```js
$('.expand').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $expand = $(this).children('.expand.hide');
    if ($expand.length >= 1) {
        $expand.removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        $(this).find('.expand').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

```css
div {
    padding: 15px;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expand">
    Some parent text
    <div class="expand hide">
        1st level child
        <div class="expand hide">
            2n level child
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example you can have more than 2 child elements

Comment: I guess now it's obvious that I'm not too experienced just yet but I'm confident in using elements that interest me. Thank you a lot for providing this, basically this is EXACTLY what I was looking for and the solution was much more simple than I thought! It really is small and simple but simplicity also means that it's easily editable so that's great!